# How to structure nested for loops?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have been studying `for` loops but I can't seem to get my head around NESTED `for` loops. I am doing a problem which requires knowledge of nested `for` loops, which I do not know how to do!

Problem:

> Write a for loop that produces the following output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
0
4
8
12
16
```

Caveat: You can only use up to two `for` loops

My Code:

```
c = 0
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(10):
        print(i * c)
        c = c + 1
```

Any help will be appreciated. I just cannot get my head around nested `for` loops. It would be great if anybody could guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `c` variable, you can multiply by `j`.

The inner loop shouldn't go up to `10` every time. Notice that as the multiplyer increases, the number of iterations goes down -- each time stops before `20`. So you need to divide `20` by `i` to get the number of iterations.

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(20//i):
        print(i * j)
```

Comment: Why do we multiply by j and not an external variable? Also what is the "//" symbol?

Comment: Why should you multiply by a different variable if it would be the same as `j`? Your loop doesn't reset `c` back to `0`.

Comment: `//` is integer division.

Answer (score 3):

One could do it like:

```
for step in range(1, 5):
    for i in range(0, 20, step):
        print(i)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
print(*[i for step in range(1, 5) for i in range(0, 20, step)], sep="\n")
```

Comment: You're missing step 4.